# Apache Artemis logging to rotate log files

Tags: activemq-artemis, log-rotation, jboss-logging

In installed Artemis broker `logging.properties`, i have included below configuration to setup log rotate

```
# File handler configuration
handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=DEBUG
handler.FILE.properties=suffix,append,autoFlush,fileName

# for log rotate
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm

handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.fileName=${artemis.instance}/log/artemis.log
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN

## Added for Log rotate
handler.FILE.rotate-size=25k
handler.FILE.max-backup-index=3
handler.FILE.rotate-on-boot=true
```

With above change when i restart the Artemis broker service, is notice the log being rotated to artemis.log.2021-09-02-14

But with the `rotate-size` 25k, the file is not getting rotated.

Below is the jboss documentation for the properties.

| properties | data type | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| max-backup-index | Integer | The maximum number of size-rotated logs that are kept. When this number is reached, the oldest log is reused. Default: 1. This setting only applies to logs that are rotated based on file size. Note that if a file is rotated with a date format suffix, it will not be purged using the max-backup-index option. |
| rotate-size | String | The maximum size that the log file can reach before it is rotated. |

My expectation in this case would be:

- every hour the log to be rotated, and only 3 set of files will be manage

```
artemis.log
artemis.log.2020-09-02-16
artemis.log.2020-09-02-15
artemis.log.2020-09-02-14

purged files
artemis.log.2020-09-02-13
```

Is there a way to check how often the log rotation is triggered by Artemis broker?

Is the configuration incorrect.

---

Using Artemis 2.17 version
After updating the properties, i am getting below exception on restarting the service.

```
2021-09-03 02:02:59,468 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222276: Failed to process changes to the logging configuration file: file:/<borker-path>/etc/logging.properties: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No property "rotateSize" setter found for handler "FILE"
at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration.setPropertyValueExpression(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:194) [jboss-logmanager-2.1.10.Final.jar:2.1.10.Final]
at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration.setPropertyValueString(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:155) [jboss-logmanager-2.1.10.Final.jar:2.1.10.Final]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.LoggingConfigurationUpdater.configureProperties(LoggingConfigurationUpdater.java:351) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.LoggingConfigurationUpdater.configureHandler(LoggingConfigurationUpdater.java:323) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.LoggingConfigurationUpdater.configureHandlerNames(LoggingConfigurationUpdater.java:363) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.LoggingConfigurationUpdater.configureLogger(LoggingConfigurationUpdater.java:193) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.LoggingConfigurationUpdater.configure(LoggingConfigurationUpdater.java:111) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.LoggingConfigurationUpdater.configure(LoggingConfigurationUpdater.java:85) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.LoggingConfigurationFileReloader.reload(LoggingConfigurationFileReloader.java:46) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.reload.ReloadManagerImpl$ReloadRegistry.check(ReloadManagerImpl.java:124) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.reload.ReloadManagerImpl.tick(ReloadManagerImpl.java:67) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.reload.ReloadManagerImpl.run(ReloadManagerImpl.java:48) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQScheduledComponent.runForExecutor(ActiveMQScheduledComponent.java:313) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQScheduledComponent.lambda$bookedRunForScheduler$2(ActiveMQScheduledComponent.java:320) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
```

may be i need to check the source code.

It was the default `logging.properties` which i used

```
# Root logger option
loggers=org.eclipse.jetty,org.jboss.logging,org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server,org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils,org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.critical,org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal,org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server,org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap,org.apache.activemq.audit.base,org.apache.activemq.audit.message,org.apache.activemq.audit.resource

# Root logger level
logger.level=INFO
# ActiveMQ Artemis logger levels
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.level=INFO
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal.level=INFO
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.level=INFO

# if you have issues with CriticalAnalyzer, setting this as TRACE would give you extra troubleshooting information.
# but do not use it regularly as it would incur in some extra CPU usage for this diagnostic.
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.critical.level=INFO

logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.level=INFO
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap.level=INFO
logger.org.eclipse.jetty.level=WARN
# Root logger handlers
logger.handlers=FILE,CONSOLE

# to enable audit change the level to INFO
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.base.level=ERROR
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.base.handlers=AUDIT_FILE
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.base.useParentHandlers=false

logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.resource.level=ERROR
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.resource.handlers=AUDIT_FILE
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.resource.useParentHandlers=false

logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.message.level=ERROR
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.message.handlers=AUDIT_FILE
logger.org.apache.activemq.audit.message.useParentHandlers=false

# Console handler configuration
handler.CONSOLE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler
handler.CONSOLE.properties=autoFlush
handler.CONSOLE.level=DEBUG
handler.CONSOLE.autoFlush=true
handler.CONSOLE.formatter=PATTERN

# File handler configuration
handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=DEBUG
handler.FILE.properties=suffix,append,autoFlush,fileName,rotateSize,maxBackupIndex,rotateOnBoot
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.fileName=${artemis.instance}/log/artemis.log
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN
## Added for Log rotate
handler.FILE.rotateSize=25600
handler.FILE.maxBackupIndex=3
handler.FILE.rotateOnBoot=true

# Formatter pattern configuration
formatter.PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d %-5p [%c] %s%E%n

#Audit logger
handler.AUDIT_FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.AUDIT_FILE.level=INFO
handler.AUDIT_FILE.properties=suffix,append,autoFlush,fileName,
handler.AUDIT_FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.AUDIT_FILE.append=true
handler.AUDIT_FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.AUDIT_FILE.fileName=${artemis.instance}/log/audit.log
handler.AUDIT_FILE.formatter=AUDIT_PATTERN

formatter.AUDIT_PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.AUDIT_PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.AUDIT_PATTERN.pattern=%d [AUDIT](%t) %s%E%n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a handful of problems with your configuration.

- If you want to use *both* time & size based rotation you need to use `org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler`. Currently you're using `org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler` which will only rotate based on time.
- You're formatting your rotation config properties incorrectly. You're using `-` characters when you should be using [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) like the rest of the properties. I believe this is because you're reading the documentation from JBoss EAP which has a slightly different configuration format than the plain properties-based configuration used by ActiveMQ Artemis.
- You aren't specifying the rotation config properties in the `properties` configuration for the `FILE` `handler`.
- You're using the size notation `k` which isn't supported in the plain properties-based configuration used by ActiveMQ Artemis.

Try using this instead:

```
handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=DEBUG
handler.FILE.properties=suffix,append,autoFlush,fileName,rotateSize,maxBackupIndex,rotateOnBoot
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.fileName=${artemis.instance}/log/artemis.log
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN
handler.FILE.rotateSize=25600
handler.FILE.maxBackupIndex=3
handler.FILE.rotateOnBoot=true
```

Comment: I included the recommended values, looks like the setters not recognized. Edited the question with exception message.

Comment: I used this exact configuration in my `logging.properties` and everything worked fine. Can you paste your full `logging.properties`?

Comment: The logging.properties used was the default one generated during broker creation. When i restart, i noticed the log file gets created as new one.

Comment: You're not using the configuration I recommended. You're still using `handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler`. This handler doesn't have a `rotateSize` parameter which is why you're getting the error. You need to use `handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler`. I updated my answer to make this configuration error more clear.

Comment: my bad you are correct. it didn't throw exception..